# Mysql Select a specified number of results based their value sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation where i need to query for each 6 value = 0  back to back as 1.

```
SELECT count(price) FROM TABLE WHERE p_value = 0 AND availability ="outofstock"
```

I need it to count every 6 back to back results as one so if there are 
12 results the count should return 2 and if there are other odd or even numbers like 13 back to back or 16 back to back it should ignore if there are 18 results it should return 3.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `p_value` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `availability` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;


INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `price`, `p_value`, `availability`, `product_id`) VALUES
(1, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(2, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(3, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(4, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(5, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(6, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(7, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(8, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(9, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(10, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(11, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(12, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(13, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(14, 10, 3, 'available', 5),
(15, 10, 1, 'available', 2),
(16, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 99),
(17, 10, 3, 'available', 8),
(18, 10, 4, 'available', 30),
(19, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 26),
(20, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 12),
(21, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(22, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(23, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3),
(24, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 11),
(25, 10, 0, 'outofstock', 3);
```

Comment: What do you mean back to back?

Comment: their sequence for example if  id 1 2 3 4 5 6 has a value of 0 count it as one but if the ids 1 2 3 4 5 has a value of zero and 6 doesn't don't count it

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Still learning about it.